# how to overlap a layout with image view and text over the other layout as a stack/pile

Tags: android, css, android-layout, layout

I am in a weird situation in my existing project. In my project i want to inflate one layout over the other as a stack dynamically. At present in my project i managed to show the layouts one below the other vertically by appending them, this approach has been chosen by me because even though i am trying to show it as stack only one image is appearing at the front during runtime instead of a bunch. In order to understand my problem please go through the following image links and code

[desired result](http://s12.postimg.org/k3n9zqup9/requiredstack.png)

[acquired_result_when_tried_to_acheive_desired_result](http://s28.postimg.org/amlujl6sd/withoutorientation.png)

[approached way](http://postimg.org/image/sm7ir63ap/)

Parent layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imagegallery"
android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

child layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/close" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/right" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/deelpizza"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
            android:background="@drawable/text_bg" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageprew"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageprew"
                android:text="This is an exclusive Deel good for today only clime this  deel before its close!"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageprew" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:background="@drawable/text_bg"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
        />
        -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeImage"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locationText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="woodfire pizza, Los Gatos CA\nLimited time offer, redeemable today only."
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/locationText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="1 large, 2 topping pizza"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="$15"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

JavaCode:

```
 private void addImagesToThegallery() {
    LinearLayout imageGallery = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imagegallery);
    //imageGallery.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 30);
    LayoutInflater layoutInfralte=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    List views=new ArrayList();
      View view;
    for(int j=0; j<=5; j++)
    {
        view=layoutInfralte.inflate(R.layout.newdeels, null);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        views.add(view);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<views.size(); i++)
    {
        imageGallery.addView((View) views.get(i));
      }
```

Please go through my code and let me know where am i going wrong and let me know if i am unclear anywhere

Comment: check out : https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards

Comment: Why are you using 2 iteration for adding view inside parent layout. Instead of 2 iteration you can make first one.

Comment: views.add(view); replace with imageGallery.add(view); and remove second iteration

Comment: @vipul_asri hi thank you for your response ur response actually worked. But now i am dealing with another situation where-in i would like to update details based on swipe for eg: if a card is swiped right it should be gestured as like where as if a card is swiped left it should be gestured as dislike so how to actually code these swipe gestures can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

**Change the margin top to make views come down a bit**

```
  for(int j=0; j<=5; j++)
        {
            view=layoutInfralte.inflate(R.layout.newdeels, null);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.setMargins(left,5*j, right, bottom);
            view.setLayoutParams(lp);
            views.add(view);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<views.size(); i++)
        {
            imageGallery.addView((View) views.get(i));
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout following

**[Github : Material Recent Layout](https://github.com/ZieIony/MaterialRecents)**

[image: Material Recent Layout]

**Usage**

```
RecentsList recents = (RecentsList) findViewById(R.id.recents);
recents.setAdapter(new RecentsAdapter() {
    @Override
    public String getTitle(int position) {
        return "Item "+position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position) {
        ImageView iv  =new ImageView(RecentsActivity.this);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mazda);
        iv.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        return iv;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getIcon(int position) {
        return getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeaderColor(int position) {
        return colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

**Note**

You need to modify as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) in your parent layout. Set different margins in child views to achive an effect of stack.

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top

Answer (score 0):

> check out : github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards

As per your response :

*hi thank you for your response ur response actually worked. But now i am dealing with another situation where-in i would like to update details based on swipe for eg: if a card is swiped right it should be gestured as like where as if a card is swiped left it should be gestured as dislike so how to actually code these swipe gestures can you please help me out*

@ashwin for that you should have a `like` and `dislike` drawable or a custom view.

```
    card.setOnCardDimissedListener(new CardModel.OnCardDismissedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onLike() {
          Log.d("Swipeable Card", "I liked it");
     }

     @Override
     public void onDislike() {
          Log.d("Swipeable Card", "I did not liked it");
     }
});
```

Use above snippet to `show` or `hide` the view of `like` or `dislike` in respective methods that is `onLike()` and `onDislike()`.

**Edit 1:**

I figured out the problem what you are facing, If you are simply implementing the `Sample Code`. Then it clearly shows that `CardContainer` has `SimpleCardStackAdapter` as adapter and `CardModel` are added to it using *new* operator. Except the last element of `CardModel` that is added separately and cardModel Listener is applied on last element only. If you want to apply it on all elements. Then you should have to add the elements to `SimpleCardStackAdapter` by `ArrayList` of `CardModel`.

Comment: Hi i have already used this but a problem with this is only the last card swipe gesture is recognized instead of the cards from the beginning for eg: if a stack consists of four cards for the first three cards the swipe gestures aren't recognized but for the last card it is printing in the log that the card has been swiped right could you please help me out with that

Comment: @ashwin please see `Edit1`.